# C# Where does the memory overhead come from

Tags: c#, memory

I'm having a little resource problem here. It seems that .NET is creating an aweful lot of memory overhead and/or doesn't release memory it shouldn't need. But to the problem:

I have an object which reads a STL file of the following class:

```
public class cSTLBinaryDataModel
{
    public byte[] header { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 triangleCount { get { return Convert.ToUInt32(triangleList.Count); } }
    public List<cSTLTriangle> triangleList { get; private set; }

    public  cSTLBinaryDataModel()
    {
        header = new byte[80];
        triangleList = new List<cSTLTriangle>();
    }

    public void ReadFromFile(string in_filePath)
    {
        byte[] stlBytes;
//Memory logpoint 1
        stlBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(in_filePath);
//Memory logpoint 2
        ReadHeader(stlBytes.SubArray(0, cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER));
        ReadTriangles(stlBytes.SubArray(cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER, stlBytes.Length - cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER));
//Evaluate memory logpoints here
    }

    private void ReadHeader(byte[] in_header)
    {
        header = in_header;
    }

    private void ReadTriangles(byte[] in_triangles)
    {
        UInt32 numberOfTriangles = BitConverter.ToUInt32(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_triangles.SubArray(0, 4)), 0);
//Memory logpoint 3
        for (UInt32 i = 0; i < numberOfTriangles; i++)
        {
            triangleList.Add(new cSTLTriangle(in_triangles.SubArray(Convert.ToInt32(i * cConstants.BYTES_PER_TRIANGLE + 4), Convert.ToInt32(cConstants.BYTES_PER_TRIANGLE))));
        }
//Memory logpoint 4
    }
}
```

My STL file is quite big (but can get even bigger); it contains 10533050 triangles, so it's roughly 520 MB in size on disk. The class `cSTLTriangle` which is added to `triangleList` is the following:

```
public class cSTLTriangle
{
    public cVector normalVector { get; private set; }
    public cVector[] vertices { get; private set; }
    public UInt16 attributeByteCount { get; private set; }
    public bool triangleFilledWithExternalValues { get; private set; }

    public cSTLTriangle(byte[] in_bytes)
    {
        Initialize();
        normalVector = new cVector(BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(0, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(4, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(8, 4)), 0));
        vertices[0] = new cVector(BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(12, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(16, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(20, 4)), 0));
        vertices[1] = new cVector(BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(24, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(28, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(32, 4)), 0));
        vertices[2] = new cVector(BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(36, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(40, 4)), 0),
            BitConverter.ToSingle(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(44, 4)), 0));
        attributeByteCount = BitConverter.ToUInt16(cHelpers.HandleLSBFirst(in_bytes.SubArray(48, 2)), 0);
        triangleFilledWithExternalValues = true;
    }

    public cSTLTriangle(cVector in_vertex1, cVector in_vertex2, cVector in_vertex3)
    {
        Initialize();
        vertices[0] = in_vertex1;
        vertices[1] = in_vertex2;
        vertices[2] = in_vertex3;
        normalVector = cVectorOperations.CrossProduct(cVectorOperations.GetDirectionVector(vertices[0], vertices[1]), cVectorOperations.GetDirectionVector(vertices[0], vertices[2]));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Resets object to a defined state
    /// </summary>
    private void Initialize()
    {
        vertices = new cVector[3];
        //from here on not strictly necessary, but it helps with resetting the object after an error
        normalVector = new cVector(0, 0, 0);
        vertices[0] = new cVector(0, 0, 0);
        vertices[1] = new cVector(0, 0, 0);
        vertices[2] = new cVector(0, 0, 0);
        attributeByteCount = 0;
        triangleFilledWithExternalValues = false;
    }
}
```

With the class `cVector` being: (Sorry for this much code)

```
public class cVector:ICloneable
{
    public float component1 { get; set; }
    public float component2 { get; set; }
    public float component3 { get; set; }
    public double Length { get { return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(component1, 2) + Math.Pow(component2, 2) + Math.Pow(component3, 2)); } }

    public cVector(float in_value1, float in_value2, float in_value3)
    {
        component1 = in_value1;
        component2 = in_value2;
        component3 = in_value3;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new cVector(component1, component2, component3);
    }
}
```

If I count what sizes the used types in my classes have, it amounts to 51 bytes for one instance of `cSTLTriangle`. I am aware that there has to be an overhead to accomodate functions and such. But, if I multiply this size by the number of triangles, I end up at 512,3 MB, which is quite in tune with the actual file size. I would imagine the `triangleList` takes up roughly the same amount of memory (again allowing for slight overhead, it's a `List<T>` nontheless), but no! (Using GC.GetTotalMemory(false) to evaluate memory)

From Logpoint 1 to Logpoint 2, there is an increase by 526660800 bytes, this is quite accurately the size of the STL file which is loaded into the byte array.
Between Logpoint 3 and Logpoint 2 there is an increase of roughly the same amount, understandable, because I pass a subarray to the `ReadTriangles` method. The `SubArray` is code I found here on SO (could this be the devil in desguise?):

```
public static T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] data, int index, int length)
{
    T[] result = new T[length];
    Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
    return result;
}
```

Things get ridiculous at the next Logpoint. Between Logpoint 4 and Logpoint 3 there is an increase in memory usage of about roughly 4.73 times the size of the original STL file (As you can see, I make heavy use of `.SubArray` while parsing each triangle).

When I let the program continue, there is no significant increase in memory usage: good, but also no decrease at all: bad. I would expect the `byte[]` holding the file to release memory, since it goes out of scope, as does the sub array I passed to `ReadTriangles(byte[] ...)`, but somehow they don't. *And I end up with an "overhead" of 5.7 times the size of my raw STL data.*

**Is this usual behaviour? Does the .NET runtime keep memory allocated (even if it has been extended to disk), just like Photoshop does, once it got hold of some jucy RAM? How can I reduce the memory footprint of this combination of classes?**

EDIT:

- The Problem occures on Win7 Enterprise, x64. .NET 4.5, compiled for x64 (but also AnyCPU)
- I called `GC.Collect()` after the object creation was done (so outside the object itself) and nothing happened. Only after setting the object reference to `null` I got the memory back

Comment: Without looking at the numbers, I can say that a possible reason for no immediate decrease is that although an object is *eligible* for GC, the GC doesn't have a reason to reclaim it, likely because there is plenty of space left in the heaps it uses to manage the object generations. Have you tried forcing a GC collection of all generations to observe the reduction in memory usage?

Comment: Avoid reading big files all at once. Open a stream to the file and read bytes one by one or block by block as you need, and close the stream.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I used `GC.Collect()` right after the object creation finished: to no avail. Only after I set the Object to null (thus killing the reference) it gave me back my memory.

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk "to no avail" sounds like nothing was available to collect. I'm fairly certain forcing the collection still does what it says, but you need to be confident that your items really *are* ready for collection. Once the reduction occurs, does it fall into the region you expect or does it still seem to hold onto too much memory? At the OS level, processes are not forced to relinquish working set until there is memory pressure. The GC has some algorithms to determine how / when to reduce the heaps it uses for storing per-generation objects, but I can't remember specifics.

Comment: Making your vector class a `struct` would save you a bunch of bytes per vector, and seeing how you have quite a few, it might actually make a difference in this case.

Comment: I suggest you use BinaryReader to read the stream of the file, and pass the reader to sub-parsers, thus lowering the amount of "extra" bytes you must save in memory to zero, as the whole file is being read in a single pass and no information is copied into sub-arrays for sub-parsing.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth No, it falls back to the expected amount, so basically my Object is just way too big.

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk In that case, what is happening is you are growing the memory usage due to your implementation requiring copies of the array (`SubArray` most likely), but the GC either has no reason to do a collect or no reason to reduce it's heap sizes afterwards as the system as a whole is not under memory pressue. If you have proven that you are using an expected amount of memory, then you don't need to concern yourself if the CLR holds onto more than you need after some work completes. Unless this is a server application or windows service.

Comment: `GC.Collect()`, first, doesn't "force" memory collection, it only hints the GC that "now should be a good time to collect", and shouldn't be called if not necessary (I suggest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx). and second, it will never free any memory if there are still references to those objects in your code: that's the actual point of garbage collection in first place. Once you remove the references, the memory is freed up when the Garbage Collector thinks it's a good time (either because your application is going to be idle, or because there's memory pressure)

Comment: @Jcl Thats what I thought. Leave the GC to do its job.
Might I point everyone gently to the `SubArray` extension? Maybe there's something broken?

Comment: @Chris: Can a struct hold a property (get only) and implement interfaces?

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk `SubArray` looks good to me, however, it's returning a new array so make sure you destroy the references (by setting to `null` the old arrays) if you don't need them any more

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk yes, a struct can implement an interface, but there are some limitations and caveats with the boxing of the objects... recommended read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/05/477238.aspx

Comment: @Chris: Using structs saves roughly half the memory! That is amazing. Why are they so different? Is it because they are inherited directly from System.Object?

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk A class has an overhead of 8-12 bytes, so with 10 million triangles each with 4 vectors, that quickly adds up. And additionally you'll have four references extra in the triangle class when you use a class, which you won't have with a struct since it's stored directly in the triangle class.

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk take care when using structs implementing interfaces (as explained by my previous link), since everytime you cast it, a new object will be created (since structs in c# are value types, not reference types, so each variable holds a new copy of the object in memory). If you have references to both copies, memory can add up at a later stage, rendering the savings useless. I'm not saying "don't do it", i'm saying "use with caution" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Memory overhead**

Your `cVector` class adds *alot* of memory overhead. On a 32-bit system, any reference object has a memory overhead of *12 bytes* (although 4 of those are free to be used by fields if possible), if I recall correctly. Let's go with an overhead of 8 bytes. So in your case with 10,000,000 triangles, each containing 4 vectors, that adds upp to:

> 10,000,000 * 4 * 8 = 305 MB of overhead

If you're running on a 64-bit system it's twice that:

> 10,000,000 * 4 * 16 = 610 MB of overhead

On top of this, you also have the overhead of the four references each `cSTLTriangle` will have to the vectors, giving you:

> 10,000,000 * 4 * 4 = 152 MB (32-bit)
>
> 10,000,000 * 4 * 8 = 305 MB (64-bit)

As you can see this all builds up to quite a hefty bit of overhead.

So, in this case, I would suggest you make `cVector` a `struct`. As discussed in the comments, a struct can implement interfaces (as well as properties and methods). Just be aware of the [caveats](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/05/477238.aspx) that @Jcl mentioned.

You have the same issue with your `cSTLTriangle` class (about 76/152 MB overhead for 32-bit and 64-bit, respectively), although at its size I'm not sure I want to recommend going with struct on that. Others here might have useful insights on that matter.

Additionally, due to padding and object layout, the overhead might actually be even larger, but I haven't taken that into account here.

**List capacity**

Using the `List<T>` class with that amount of objects can cause some wasted memory. As @Matthew Watson mentions, when the list's internal array has no more room, it will be expanded. In fact, it will double it's capacity every time that happens. In a test with your number of 10533050 entries, the capacity of the list ended up at 16777216 entries, giving an overhead of:

> ( 16777216 - 10533050 ) * 4 byte reference = 23 MB (32-bit)
>
> ( 16777216 - 10533050 ) * 8 byte reference = 47 MB (64-bit)

So since you know the number of triangles in advance, I would recommend just going with a simple array. Manually setting the `Capacity` of a list works too.

**Other issues**

The other issues that have been discussed in the comments should not give you any memory overhead, but they sure will put alot of unnecessary pressure on the GC. Especially the `SubArray` method which, while very practical, will create many millions of garbage arrays for the GC to handle. I suggest skipping that and indexing into the array manually, even if it's more work.

Another issue is reading the entire file at once. This will be both slower and use more memory than reading it piece by piece. Directly using a `BinaryReader` as others have suggested might not be possible due to the endianness issues you need to deal with. One complicated option *could* be to use memory mapped files, that would let you access the data without having to care about if it's been read or not, leaving the details to the OS.

(man I hope I got all these numbers right)

Comment: The numbers look quite reasonable, I'll look into it again once it's monday, but thanks for your extensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you can try to decrease memory usage.

Firstly, if possible you should rewrite your file loading code so that it only loads the data it needs rather than loading the whole file at once.

For example, you could read the header as a single block, and then read the data for each triangle as a single block (in a loop).

Secondly, it's possible that your large object heap is suffering from fragmentation - and the garbage collector doesn't move large objects, so it can't be defragmented. (This issue if fixed for .Net 4.51, but you have to explicitly enable large object heap defragmentation, and instigate it explicitly.)

You may be able to mitigate this problem by pre-sizing your `triangleList`.

At the moment, you add each triangle to `triangleList` in turn, starting with a list with zero capacity. This means that every so often the list's capacity will be exceeded, causing it to be expanded.

When the list is expanded by adding an item to it when it's at capacity, it:

- Creates a new internal buffer twice the size of the current buffer.
- Copies the old buffer to the new one.
- Deletes the old buffer.
- Copies the new item to the new buffer.

The problem where is twofold:

1. A lot of redundant copying is going on.
2. If the internal buffer exceeds the threshold for putting objects on the large object heap, you might be getting heap fragmentation.

Since you know in advance the maximum size of the triangle list you can solve this issue by setting the list's capacity before adding items to it:

```
triangleList.Capacity = numberOfTriangles;
```

Comment: I have enabled `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`.
Setting the capacity seems not to do the trick however.

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` only works in 64 bits, and it only tells that "a single object of over 2gb is allowed". It doesn't do anything if there's no single object that has over 2gb allocated

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk You could download the 14 day free trial of  Redgate's Ants Memory Profiler and have a play with it: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Comment: Visual Studio (2013 Pro and up, at least) also has a pretty decent .NET memory profiler which you can use

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk seems it was there in 2012 too (I skipped 2012 so I didn't know): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/04/04/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After logpoint 2 maybe you could try splitting out the code a bit so that you have a

```
byte[] header
byte[] triangles
```

and once you're done splitting the original byte array set it to null and then you can use `System.GC.Collect()` to force the garbage collector to run. This should save you a bit of memory.

```
 public void ReadFromFile(string in_filePath)
    {
        byte[] stlBytes;
//Memory logpoint 1
        stlBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(in_filePath);
//Memory logpoint 2
        byte[] header = stlBytes.SubArray(0, cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER);
        byte[] triangles = stlBytes.SubArray(cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER, stlBytes.Length - cConstants.BYTES_IN_HEADER);
        ReadHeader(header);
        ReadTriangles(triangles);
        stlBytes = null;
        System.GC.Collect();
//Evaluate memory logpoints here
    }
```

Comment: Hm, I'll give it a try, but I'm not particularly keen on calling GC.Collect, because it is supposed to know when to do what, as others have pointed out may times.

Comment: You might not actually need to call it once you set stlBytes to null. So you can probably remove that line.

Comment: Sorry, but neither GC.Collect nor setting to null works.